# Conditional Formatting based on values in a separate column based on Data Validation from a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm making a spreadsheet journal with :
 - a main entry on sheet1
 - a static list of names and data on sheet2

In sheet1 I input values through Data Validation based on names in sheet2. Later on I add a value in sheet1. This value needs to be compared to a minimum and maximum value, that is listed in sheet2, and then color coded through conditional formatting based on a % deviation from the values in sheet2. For instance:

**In sheet1 I have the data:**

```
     A                          B
1    value                      OG 
2    British Brown Ale          1.045
```

value `British Brown Ale` is input through the dropdown populated from the Data Validation list.  In `B2` I have a value for "OG" being `1.045`.

**In sheet2 the data looks like:**

```
     A                          B          C
1    value                      min OG     max OG 
2    British Brown Ale          1.040      1.052
```

In the row with "British Brown Ale":

- in column 2 ("Min OG") I have a value of `1.040`
- in column 3 ("Max OG") I have a value of `1.052`

**Desired Result**

I need to make:

1. the range from 1.040 to 1.052 100% within the range and color code that green,
2. If the value in `sheet1!B2` was for instance up to 10% outside of this range it would be color coded yellow,
3. and over 10% would be color coded red.

How do I use conditional formatting that can compare values like above?

Will I need scripts to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible doing with only formulas. The best way is to use only [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) in order to make all formulas espand automatically.

**Sheet2**

Add two columns: "min - 10%" and "max + 10%"

in cell D2:

```
=ArrayFormula(OFFSET(B2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))/1.1)
```

in cell E2:

```
=ArrayFormula(OFFSET(C2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))*1.1)
```

The result:

[image]

**Sheet1**

4 formulas to get "min",    "max",  "min-10%",  "max+10%"

in cell C2:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)),sheet1!A:E,2,0))
```

in cell D2:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)),sheet1!A:E,3,0))
```

in cell E2:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)),sheet1!A:E,4,0))
```

in cell F2:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)),sheet1!A:E,5,0))
```

And one formula to have color:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(--(OFFSET(B2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))<OFFSET(E2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)))+B2>F2,"red",if((OFFSET(B2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))>=OFFSET(C2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)))*(+OFFSET(B2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))<=OFFSET(D2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))),"green","yellow")))
```

The result:

[image]

**Conditional Formatting rules for Sheet1**

Select column B, add 3 new conditional formatting (CF) rules, custom formula:

first, paint green:

```
=$G1="green"
```

next, paint yellow:

```
=$G1="yellow"
```

next, paint red:

```
=$G1="red"
```

Then wou may hide extra columns.

The result:

[image]

---

I think, that's all is possible to do with only 3 huge arrayformulas inside CF, without doing extra columns, but it's hard to build one.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with ArrayFormula and I'm not entirely sure I understand what it does in the way you've set it up where - But I will try to make this work and report back here.

Before you posted this I cooked up a working formula that triggers on the green color when used in a cell, but I couldn't get it working with Conditional Formatting since I was referencing a different sheet, and that is apparently not possible.

`=IF(AND(H4*1000>INDEX(Styles!M:M,MATCH(F4,Styles!C:C,0)),H4*1000<=INDEX(Styles!N:N,MATCH(F4,Styles!C:C,0))),"Inside Range: Green","Outside Range")`

Comment: Couldn't reply all in one message.
To clearify; `F4` being the Data validated `"British Brown Ale"`.
`Styles!` being sheet2. `H4` being the `OG` in sheet1. Column `Styles!M` being the reference `min OG`. `Styles!N` being the reference `max OG`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using the ArrayFormula methods without having to edit Sheet2?
It's a direct 1:1 copy of an official datasheet and would prefer not to do any changes to it.
In the end there will be a total of 3 ranges of Min/Max that will be color coded based on this, so the fewer extra columns the better. The reference sheet isn't very large - only 119 styles - so "heavy" algorithms should work.

Comment: Yes, you need to replace formulas from sheet2 into sheet1

Comment: Once I managed to wrap my head around how the different formulas worked this is actually quite quick to implement into my sheet - despite being very space intensive. I've used more than a full alphabet worth of `OFFSET` ranges, but the alternative - making most of it into one formula - became exceedingly complex the more info I needed to add.

This works great, thank you!

Comment: I have one issue that I haven't been able to solve yet.
For whichever reason, the `Color` (G Column) only takes the first `OG` into account. If I set one of the others to something way off it will not trigger the red range, but if I change the first `OG` input to something outside the range the colors for the others follow.
I'm pretty new to this so still trying to figure out why it happens.
I'll update if I find it.

Comment: Figured it out! It was a combination of mixed localizations and a bad formula.
Correct formula for color (using German Localizaiton to make it "EU number friendly"): `=ArrayFormula(if(--(OFFSET(B2:B;;;COUNTA(A2:A))<OFFSET(E2:E;;;COUNTA(A2:A)))+--(OFFSET(B2:B;;;COUNTA(A2:A))>OFFSET(F2:F;;;COUNTA(A2:A)));"red";if((OFFSET(B2:B;;;COUNTA(A2:A))>=OFFSET(C2:C;;;COUNTA(A2:A)))*(+OFFSET(B2:B;;;COUNTA(A2:A))<=OFFSET(D2:D;;;COUNTA(A2:A)));"green";"yellow")))`